# How to I repaint my JFrame to update the variable values?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint, static

```
package greed;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;


public class Greed extends JPanel {

    public static BufferedImage slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5;

    public static int diceOne, diceTwo, diceThree, diceFour, diceFive = 0;

    public static String diceLoc1 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/DiceBlankResize.jpg";
    public static String diceLoc2 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/DiceBlankResize.jpg";
    public static String diceLoc3 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/DiceBlankResize.jpg";
    public static String diceLoc4 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/DiceBlankResize.jpg";
    public static String diceLoc5 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/DiceBlankResize.jpg";
    public static String diceLoc6 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/DiceBlankResize.jpg";

    public static boolean canRerollDiceOne = true;
    public static boolean canRerollDiceTwo = true;
    public static boolean canRerollDiceThree = true;
    public static boolean canRerollDiceFour = true;
    public static boolean canRerollDiceFive = true;

    public static double playerOneScore = 0;
    public static double playerTwoScore = 0;
    public static double playerThreeScore = 0;
    public static double playerFourScore = 0;

    public static double OneValue = 100;
    public static double TwoValue = 0;
    public static double ThreeValue = 0;
    public static double FourValue = 0;
    public static double FiveValue = 50;
    public static double SixValue = 0;

    public static int playerTurn = 0;

    /*
    public static int diceOneRoll;
    public static int diceTwoRoll;
    public static int diceThreeRoll;
    public static int diceFourRoll;
    public static int diceFiveRoll;
    */

    public static String choiceReroll = "";

    // The menus
    public static String menu = "";
    public static int rerollSel;

    public static byte[] contents;
    public static int pointer = 0;

    public static JFrame f = new JFrame("Greed");
    public static JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    public static JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
    public static JTextArea jTextArea2 = new JTextArea();
    public static JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTextArea1);
    public static JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    public static JLabel diceLab1 = new JLabel("Dice 1");
    public static JLabel diceLab2 = new JLabel("Dice 2");
    public static JLabel diceLab3 = new JLabel("Dice 3");
    public static JLabel diceLab4 = new JLabel("Dice 4");
    public static JLabel diceLab5 = new JLabel("Dice 5");

    public static Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
    public static int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
    public static int ySize = 500;

    public static int height = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
    public static int width = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());

    public static int slot1x, slot2x, slot3x, slot4x, slot5x;
    public static int sloty = 550;

    public static int x1Img1 = 250;
    public static int x2Img1 = 375;
    public static int x1Img2 = 495;
    public static int x2Img2 = 620;
    public static int x1Img3 = 740;
    public static int x2Img3 = 865;
    public static int x1Img4 = 985;
    public static int x2Img4 = 1110;
    public static int x1Img5 = 1230;
    public static int x2Img5 = 1355;
    public static int yLine = 550;
    public static int yImgSize = 200;

    public static void Greed() {
        f.setJMenuBar(mb);
        //jScrollPane1.setBounds(10,60,780,500);
        //jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    }

    public void setDie1(BufferedImage slot1) {
        Greed.slot1 = slot1;
    }
    public void setDie2(BufferedImage slot2) {
        this.slot2 = slot2;
    }
    public void setDie3(BufferedImage slot3) {
        this.slot3 = slot3;
    }
    public void setDie4(BufferedImage slot4) {
        this.slot4 = slot4;
    }
    public void setDie5(BufferedImage slot5) {
        this.slot5 = slot5;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //g.drawRect(250, 550, 120, 120);
        //g.drawRect(495, 550, 120, 120);
        //g.drawRect(740, 550, 120, 120);
        //g.drawRect(985, 550, 120, 120);
        //g.drawRect(1230, 550, 120, 120);
        g.drawImage(slot1, 250, sloty, this);
        g.drawImage(slot2, 495, sloty, this);
        g.drawImage(slot3, 740, sloty, this);
        g.drawImage(slot4, 985, sloty, this);
        g.drawImage(slot5, 1230, sloty, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Greed gui = new Greed();
        gui.launchFrame();
        //run();

        Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new Greed());

        Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Greed...");
            do {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play? (yes/no)");
            menu = is.next();
                switch (menu) {
                    case "yes":
                        diceOne = 0;
                        diceTwo = 0;
                        diceThree = 0;
                        diceFour = 0;
                        diceFive = 0;
                        Game();

                        break;
                    case "no":
                        System.out.println("Goodbye...");
                        System.exit(0);

                        break;
                    default:
                        invalidInput();

                        break;
                }
            } while (!"yes".equals(menu) || !"no".equals(menu));
    }

    public static void Game() throws IOException {
        rollDiceOne();
        rollDiceTwo();
        rollDiceThree();
        rollDiceFour();
        rollDiceFive();

        displayDice();
        displayDiceValues();
        f.repaint();
        System.out.println(diceLoc1);

        choiceRerollDice();
    }

    public static void choiceRerollDice() {
        Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                if (!canRerollDiceOne && !canRerollDiceTwo && !canRerollDiceThree && !canRerollDiceFour && !canRerollDiceFive) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, but you may not reroll any more dice...");
                displayDiceValues();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else {
        System.out.println("Would you like to reroll any (more) dice? (yes/no)");
            choiceReroll = is.next();
                switch (choiceReroll) {
                    case "yes":
                        rerollDice();
                        break;
                    case "no":
                        //endTurn();
                        displayDice();
                        displayDiceValues();
                        f.repaint();
                        System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    default:
                        invalidInput();
                    }
                }
            } while (!"yes".equals(choiceReroll) || !"no".equals(choiceReroll));
    }

    public static void rerollDice() {
        Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which dice would you like to reroll? (1-5)");
        rerollSel = is.nextInt();
                switch (rerollSel) {
                    case 1:
                        if (canRerollDiceOne) {
                            diceOne = 0;
                            rollDiceOne();
                            canRerollDiceOne = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, but you may not reroll this dice!");
                            choiceRerollDice();
                        }

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (canRerollDiceTwo) {
                            diceTwo = 0;
                            rollDiceTwo();
                            canRerollDiceTwo = false;
                            }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, but you may not reroll this dice!");
                            choiceRerollDice();
                        }

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (canRerollDiceThree) {
                        diceThree = 0;
                        rollDiceThree();
                        canRerollDiceThree = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, but you may not reroll this dice!");
                            choiceRerollDice();
                        }

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (canRerollDiceFour) {
                        diceFour = 0;
                        rollDiceFour();
                        canRerollDiceFour = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, but you may not reroll this dice!");
                            choiceRerollDice();
                        }

                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (canRerollDiceFive) {
                        diceFive = 0;
                        rollDiceFive();
                        canRerollDiceFive = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, but you may not reroll this dice!");
                            choiceRerollDice();
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid dice number...");
                        System.out.println("Please enter a dice 1-5...");
                        rerollDice();

                        break;
                }
    }

    public static void invalidInput() {
        System.out.println("Invalid input...");
        System.out.println("Please enter either 'yes' or 'no'...");
    }

    public static void playerTurn() {
        switch (playerTurn) {
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
        }
    }

    public static void rollDiceOne() {
        diceOne = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
    }
    public static void rollDiceTwo() {
        diceTwo = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
    }
    public static void rollDiceThree() {
        diceThree = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
    }
    public static void rollDiceFour() {
        diceFour = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
    }
    public static void rollDiceFive() {
        diceFive = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
    }

    public static void resetDiceOne() {
        diceOne = 0;
    }
    public static void resetDiceTwo() {
        diceTwo = 0;
    }
    public static void resetDiceThree() {
        diceThree = 0;
    }
    public static void resetDiceFour() {
        diceFour = 0;
    }
    public static void resetDiceFive() {
        diceFive = 0;
    }

    public static void displayDice() {
        switch (diceOne) {
            case 1:
                diceLoc1 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice1Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 2:
                diceLoc1 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice2Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 3:
                diceLoc1 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice3Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 4:
                diceLoc1 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice4Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 5:
                diceLoc1 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice5Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 6:
                diceLoc1 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice6Resize.jpg";
                break;
        }
        switch (diceTwo) {
            case 1:
                diceLoc2 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice1Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 2:
                diceLoc2 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice2Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 3:
                diceLoc2 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice3Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 4:
                diceLoc2 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice4Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 5:
                diceLoc2 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice5Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 6:
                diceLoc2 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice6Resize.jpg";
                break;
        }
        switch (diceThree) {
            case 1:
                diceLoc3 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice1Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 2:
                diceLoc3 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice2Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 3:
                diceLoc3 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice3Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 4:
                diceLoc3 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice4Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 5:
                diceLoc3 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice5Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 6:
                diceLoc3 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice6Resize.jpg";
                break;
        }
        switch (diceFour) {
            case 1:
                diceLoc4 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice1Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 2:
                diceLoc4 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice2Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 3:
                diceLoc4 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice3Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 4:
                diceLoc4 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice4Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 5:
                diceLoc4 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice5Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 6:
                diceLoc4 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice6Resize.jpg";
                break;
        }
        switch (diceFive) {
            case 1:
                diceLoc5 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice1Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 2:
                diceLoc5 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice2Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 3:
                diceLoc5 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice3Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 4:
                diceLoc5 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice4Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 5:
                diceLoc5 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice5Resize.jpg";
                break;
            case 6:
                diceLoc5 = "C:/Users/Kameron/Downloads/Dice/Dice6Resize.jpg";
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void displayDiceValues() {
        System.out.println("Dice One = " + diceOne);
        System.out.println("Dice Two = " + diceTwo);
        System.out.println("Dice Three = " + diceThree);
        System.out.println("Dice Four = " + diceFour);
        System.out.println("Dice Five = " + diceFive);
    }

    public static void diceValuable() {

    }

    public static void scoreDicePlayerOne() {
        switch (diceOne) {
            case 1:

        }
    }    
    public static void scoreDicePlayerTwo() {
        switch (diceOne) {
            case 1: 

        }
    }
    public static void scoreDicePlayerThree() {
        switch (diceOne) {
            case 1: 

        }
    }
    public static void scoreDicePlayerFour() {
        switch (diceOne) {
            case 1: 

        }
    }

    public static void calculateScorePlayer1() {

    }
    public static void calculateScorePlayer2() {

    }
    public static void calculateScorePlayer3() {

    }
    public static void calculateScorePlayer4() {

    }

    public void launchFrame() throws IOException {
          // Display Frame
        BufferedImage slot1 = ImageIO.read(new File(diceLoc1));
        BufferedImage slot2 = ImageIO.read(new File(diceLoc2));
        BufferedImage slot3 = ImageIO.read(new File(diceLoc3));
        BufferedImage slot4 = ImageIO.read(new File(diceLoc4));
        BufferedImage slot5 = ImageIO.read(new File(diceLoc5));

        setDie1 contentPane1 = new setDie1(slot1);
        setDie2 contentPane2 = new setDie2(slot2);
        setDie3 contentPane3 = new setDie3(slot3);
        setDie4 contentPane4 = new setDie4(slot4);
        setDie5 contentPane5 = new setDie5(slot5);

        contentPane1.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane3.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane4.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane5.setOpaque(false);

          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          f.pack(); //Adjusts panel to components for display
          f.setVisible(true);
          f.add(jTextArea1);
          //f.add(jTextArea2);
          //f.add(jPanel1);
          //f.add(jScrollPane1);
          f.add(diceLab1);
          f.add(diceLab2);
          f.add(diceLab3);
          f.add(diceLab4);
          f.add(diceLab5);
          f.add(contentPane1);
          f.add(contentPane2);
          f.add(contentPane3);
          f.add(contentPane4);
          f.add(contentPane5);
          f.setSize(750, 500);
          jTextArea1.setSize(xSize, ySize);
          //jTextArea2.setSize(750, 50);
          //jPanel1.setSize(xSize, 120);
          jTextArea1.setLocation(0, 0);
          //jTextArea2.setLocation(0, 500);
          //jPanel1.setLocation(0, 500);
          diceLab1.setLocation(292, 515);
          diceLab2.setLocation(537, 515);
          diceLab3.setLocation(782, 515);
          diceLab4.setLocation(1027, 515);
          diceLab5.setLocation(1272, 515);
          contentPane1.setLocation(292, 515);
          contentPane2.setLocation(537, 515);
          contentPane3.setLocation(782, 515);
          contentPane4.setLocation(1027, 515);
          contentPane5.setLocation(1272, 515);
          diceLab1.setSize(36, 50);
          diceLab2.setSize(36, 50);
          diceLab3.setSize(36, 50);
          diceLab4.setSize(36, 50);
          diceLab5.setSize(36, 50);
          contentPane1.setSize(36, 50);
          contentPane2.setSize(36, 50);
          contentPane3.setSize(36, 50);
          contentPane4.setSize(36, 50);
          contentPane5.setSize(36, 50);
          //jPanel1.setBackground(Color.red);
          //jTextArea2.setBackground(Color.blue);
          Greed.this.repaint();
          System.out.println(ySize);
          System.out.println("Screen Resolution is: " + height + " x " + width);
    }

    public static void run()
    {
        redirectSystemStreams();
    }

//The following codes set where the text get redirected. In this case, jTextArea1    
 private static void updateTextArea(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        jTextArea1.append(text);
      }
    });
  }

//Followings are The Methods that do the Redirect, you can simply Ignore them. 
  private static void redirectSystemStreams() {
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
      @Override
      public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
      }

      @Override
      public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
      }

      @Override
      public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        write(b, 0, b.length);
      }
    };

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
  }
}

class setDie1 extends JPanel {
    public setDie1 (BufferedImage slot1) {
        Greed.slot1 = slot1;
    }
}
class setDie2 extends JPanel {
    public setDie2 (BufferedImage slot2) {
        Greed.slot2 = slot2;
    }
}
class setDie3 extends JPanel {
    public setDie3 (BufferedImage slot3) {
        Greed.slot3 = slot3;
    }
}
class setDie4 extends JPanel {
    public setDie4 (BufferedImage slot4) {
        Greed.slot4 = slot4;
    }
}
class setDie5 extends JPanel {
    public setDie5 (BufferedImage slot5) {
        Greed.slot5 = slot5;
    }
}
```

that is my code
when i call f.repaint(); to repaint my frame, it doesn't update anything.
when i try to call Greed.repaint(); it tells me that non-static variable cannot be referenced from static context.
what do I do?
I have been googling it for hours, I have even tried referenceObject.methodName(); but that format has not been working for me.
I know already that my code might be a bit messy since i am still mastering java and i know that i suck with static...
but any ideas?

thanks in advance,
Kameron

Comment: You `main` method is extremely dangerous and could end up blocking the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: what does that mean? sorry but i'm a bit of a noob

Comment: and how would i fix that?

Comment: Start by having a read through [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i will have a read through it and see what if i can fix it

Comment: load images to local variable, put those images as Icons to JButton (undecorated), JLabel, then only to call myButton/Label.setIcon(imageFromLocalVariable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why are you mixing a GUI with a command line interface?  All user interactions should be done via the GUI
2. Nothing is changing because nothing is being changed (from the UI's point of view).  You change the image reference, but you don't apply it to anything that can actually paint that change.

I would start by taking a much harder and longer look at ...

- [Creating a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)
- [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: well as u can see in my main() method, i call run() which allows output streams to be redirected, but i haven't yet got input streams to be redirected.

Comment: But the question is why?  GUI's are event driven environments, yet you want to try and stick to linear control